# how to load a class in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, nsbundle

How to load a class in Objective-C for iPhone application? I know tat Bundling concept is in MAC , but for iPhone can i use the same bundle concept to load a class?

Comment: The class which i've to load, is another project in XCode.so how about doing Cross Project Referencing into Targets[In Groups & Files] in my active project.??? Does this concept work?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to load? If you want to load a class from a nib you'd simply do something like:

```
YourClassName *classInstance = [[YourClassName alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourClassName" bundle:Nil];
```

Only some classes will implement the initWithNibName, such as UIViewControllers. You can also load a class from a nib from your bundle to an owner using the following:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourClassName" owner:self options:nil];
```

Comment: Can i do this for developing an iPhone application also??

Comment: Yes these are what I used in my iPhone application.

Comment: I don't want to load it from nib, i have to load a class which is in Hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

I use the way as follows

```
    Class c = NSClassFromString( YourClassNameHere );


YourClass* ojectInstance = [c new];
```